# RoR - The correct approach with multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 5 controllers and 5 views in my own project, I divided my app in these 5 main areas and I put many actions inside those areas/controllers.

I need many tables/models in my database, example: in the address content I need to separate some tables and build the correct relations to avoid duplicated fields... I want to manage address, user, person, legal entity, events, and many more.

What is the correct way to think in Rails at this point, if i create a model using scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold city name:string state_id:integer
```

I get the correct model, the controller and views automatically.

I want to manage that `City` table in another controller, one of that five controllers that I created before, I need to manage many tables in just one view, or one controller.

If you know what I need to read and help me, I would appreciate.

Comment: Ok, now i see the correct way to post code inside my text. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model is independent of controller. you can use your any model in any controller. I think it's one of the reason why [MVC architecture](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture) is important.

based on the concept, you can manage your `city` model, which is generated by `scaffold`, in any controller. just use [ORM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) in your controller directly:

```
City.first
City.find 1
```

Comment: So i should override the automatic created class and rebuild that magic actions (index, show, update....) in my own controller? Right?

Comment: what do you mean "automatic created class"? do you mean the controller or the model? if you just want to use the model generated by scaffold in other controllers, you can just use it without any modification.

Comment: I mean the controller. Is'nt it a class? So i could create the model without the scaffold option, i should create my controller and manipulate the tables/models in my own controller. I think a get the point!
So i need the rebuild the CRUD actions for every manipulated table/model in my own controller.

Comment: both controller and model are class, so I was not sure what did you mean. yeah, if you don't want to use the controller generated by scaffold, you can just generate a new model and use the model in any controller you want to. have fun with your awesome rails app :)